# open a local IP web page in flutter

Tags: flutter

I need to open a local IP web page in flutter like 192.168.4.1, 
but it didn't open wit me ...
can you help me :

this is my code

```
    final Completer<WebViewController> _controller = Completer<WebViewController>();
    String src = 'http://192.168.4.1/';     
    Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Easy Web View'),
          leading: IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.access_time),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                print("Click!");
                open = !open;

   });
        },

      ),
    ),
    body: WebView(
           initialUrl: src,
           javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
           onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
               _controller.complete(webViewController);
           },

          gestureNavigationEnabled: true,
)




)
```

Comment: Does it show an error ?

Comment: it is just the page is not reloaded...

Comment: Can you open it from your browser (on the same phone)?

Comment: yes, I can open it from the browser, but when entering the same URL in my app, it didn't work !!

Comment: Your code works fine for me with my local IP. Make sure that:
- No firewall restrictions
- Double check your server's IP address and port number

Comment: can the flutter block the local connection ??

Comment: Your server's firewall might block connections from your app

Answer (score 0):

Find out the location of adb.exe(mine is USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe), then run the following command,

```
adb.exe reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000
```

I am using the physical phone, and it's working for me.

Comment: I made it, and response to me "3000",  but in the app, nothing shown ! the page still not available!

Comment: Oh, sorry - I just copied and pasted it. "3000" should be the port number. In your case, it's 80?

Comment: its response me "adb.exe: error: cannot bind listener: Permission denied"